# Sort the list of coordinates by sums and then by its x coordinate

Tags: python, sorting

I was looking for this and couldn't find it so I decided to post it in case anyone else will try to find it.

My list looks something like this:

```
coordinates = [(5, 6), (8, 9), (1, 10)]
```

I want to sort them by sums of their coordinates and then by their first element (in an ascending order). The sorted list would then look like this:

```
[(1, 10), (5, 6), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What worked and what didn't? Please refer to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is actually very simple:

```
sorted(coordinates, key = lambda x: (sum(x), x[0]))
```

Does what I wanted.

Comment: This is actually only sorting by the first element - the `sum` is a built-in function and is the same for all elements when comparing. Try `sorted(coordinates, key = lambda x: (sum(x), x[0]))` instead.

Comment: Yes, I actually am using it like this in code, just didn't copy it and wrote it the wrong way my mistake.